# apex:actionPoller ignores interval specified

Tags: visualforce, rerender, refresh

I have an iframe on a pages with standard controller. I need to refresh this iframe, say, once in 10 seconds. For some reason apex:actionPoller ignores specified interval in seconds and performs requests once in 60 seconds (default interval). I use the following code:

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:actionPoller action='{!refresh}' rerender='relevant_content' interval="{!IF(($Setup.AppConfig__c != NULL && $Setup.AppConfig__c.RefreshInterval__c != NULL), $Setup.AppConfig__c.RefreshInterval__c, 20)}"/>
    <apex:outputPanel id='relevant_content'>
        <apex:iframe src="{!LinkToRelevantContent}" scrolling="true" height="400px" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
```

Did anybody encountered this problem?

Comment: What's the value of the App Config Refresh Interval _org wide_ setting?

Answer (score 1):

I think the value may be getting lost in the zealous null checking. Try this:

```
interval="{!BLANKVALUE($Setup.AppConfig__c.RefreshInterval__c, 20)}"
```

Consider that if 99.99% of the audience uses a 20 second value, you could eliminate the levers and dials altogether in the interest of keeping the code itself simpler. As developer you have the right :-)